# Android dynamically change Image View

Tags: android

all. I have a problem. I want when I press the button to resize the image.
This is the code in Activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    currentImage = new ImageView(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(400, 400);
    currentImage.setLayoutParams(params);


    images = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.images);

    currentImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.bronar_jenson);

    RelativeLayout l = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);
    l.addView(currentImage);

    b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            currentImage.getLayoutParams().width = 20;
        }
    });



}
```

Unfortunately it do not working as I expected - the button does not resize. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

Replace:

```
currentImage.getLayoutParams().width = 20;
```

with:

```
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(20, 400);

                l.updateViewLayout(currentImage, params);
```

You may need to make RelativeLayout l final

Comment: Than you so much ! But I have two questions.
The first one is: why if I make the picture in xml file, after trying your code an exception occurs - "The view already has a parrent". In that way it is working (when I make it dynamically), but when I make it statically(in xml) it does not working. 
The second one is: why when I try to modified the picture in onCreate only (not in listener) is works ! But when I try to modified it in listener it does not ?
This looks very important ant interesting to me. 
Thank you in advance !

Comment: The response I provided works for the code you provided in your question. I need to see the code for the other two cases (statically in xml and in listener) so I can provide an answer.

Comment: But why in the code above I had to use updateViewLayout ? Why my way didn't work and the most important - how you understand that ? I mean I can try in different situations, but I don't want to check 2 or 3 options every time .

Comment: currentImage.getLayoutParams() returns read-only values (getters) that have already been set on this view. They are not setters to be used at runtime. In your question code above currentImage.getLayoutParams().width returns a value of 400. The method updateViewLayout actually removes the view and replaces the view with new layout params - in this case image size change.